# android passing object member from alertdialog back to listview

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-alertdialog

I have a button in a TabActivity`that when clicked, opens an`AlertDialog`with 2`EditTextViews` for a name and number.

When I click the Ok `Button` to close the `Dialog`, I want to pass the name back into a `ListView` on the `TabActivity`. I can get the name to pass back to the `EditText` box `mAlertDialog` on the `TabActivity`. But something other than the name is being displayed in the `ListView`.

It looks like a reference to the object "widget" (`Widget` is an object of the class `Device`, which has `getName`, `setName` methods), com.mypackage.Device@419226e0.

I'll try to post the relevant code below (yes, I know I'm not using `Fragments`. I found it difficult to implement horizontal scrollable tabs with a `ListView` with `Fragments`):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

    public static ArrayList<Device> deviceList = new ArrayList<Device>();
    public static ArrayAdapter<Device> deviceAdapter=null;
    private static ListView deviceListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost= getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

    rButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        mAlertDialog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextresult_Name);


    rButton.setOnClickListener(onRegister);

    intent = new Intent (this, devices.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("devices")
            .setIndicator("Devices")
            .setContent(R.id.devices);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    deviceListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.rdevices);
        //Attach array adapter to data array "deviceList"
        deviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Device>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);
        //connect adapter "deviceAdapter" to listview widget so the activity listview is populated with data from the array
        deviceListView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
    }

private View.OnClickListener onRegister = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String title = "Register";
            String buttonOk = "OK";
            String buttonCancel = "Cancel";
            String madd = "address";
            String name = "widget name";


            //get rdevice.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View rView = li.inflate(R.layout.rdevice, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder adRegister = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            //set rdevice.xml to adRegister builder
            adRegister.setView(rView);

            //set title
            adRegister.setTitle(title);


            //Set EditText views to get user input

            final EditText mField = (EditText)rView.findViewById(R.id.editText_Address);
            final EditText nField = (EditText)rView.findViewById(R.id.editText_WidgetName);

            //set dialog message
        adRegister.setMessage("Message")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(buttonOk, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Device widget = new Device();


                    String madd = mField.getText().toString();
                    String name = nField.getText().toString();

                widget.setName(name);
                widget.setAddress(madd);

                Log.d(TAG,  "Address: " + madd);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Widget name: " + name);

                    //get user input and set it to result on main activity
                    mAlertDialog.setText(nField.getText());

                    deviceAdapter.add(widget);
                    deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(buttonCancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {

                }
            });



        //Create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = adRegister.create();

        //show it
        adRegister.show();

        }

    };
```

On debug, there are no errors in logcat.

However, when I watch the expression `mAlertDialog` it says

> Unable to retrieve the correct enclosing instance of this

Even though the correct name is displayed in the app. When I let the program finish after debug, this reference is displayed in the `ListView` "com.mypackage.Device@419226e0" instead of the name I typed in the `AlertDialog` box.

Does this have something to do with scope or anonymous inner classes? Please help. I'm not that familiar with Java so I getting lost in the nuts and bolts here.

Comment: `mAlertDialog.setText(nField.getText());` - As `nField` is an `EditText`, you need to use `nField.getText().toString()`.

Comment: mAlertDialog is already correctly displaying the name I typed into nField. The problem is with what is being displayed in deviceListView.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it to work. This was very helpful: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=6816874 , specifically this quote

> You may be wondering how the ListView will display the Product object and which property of the Product object will be displayed. The answer is very simple, by default Android ListView control renders a simple TextView inside every ListView item and TextView control can only display simple text. Notice how the toString() function is overridden in the Product class we defined above. Whatever String you will return from the object toString() function will be displayed in the TextView rendered in the ListView items.

Basically, in my Device.java class, I had to override the toString method to specify which object member to pass, so I included this code

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.name;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.